# Android Span or Non-Breaking Space Causing line break and text duplication (4.0 ICS)

Tags: android

I'm using several text views with heavy use of spans.

**The Problem:** Sometimes in my app (specifically on Ice Cream Sandwich) I will see a line break that isn't in the text string, along with text duplication. See the image below for an example. Notice how the third sentence begins, then there is a line break, then the text is duplicated and the sentence finishes.

[image]

**Code:**

```
tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reader_list_item, parent, false);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = ssbList.get(position);
tv.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

When I debug into the code, the variable 'ssb' properly only contains the text ..."3 not domineering over those in your charge, but being examples to the flock. 4 And when the chief"...

**Some specifics I've noticed from playing around with it for a few hours:**
The conditions that cause the bug seem to have something to with with the overall width of the rendered text. For instance, with the text pictured above, if I turn off bold span on the numbers, the pictured text will show properly, however if I leave the bold span, andturn off the color change span on the number (which doesn't change the width at all), the issue persists.

It's also worth noting that after each number I'm using a non-breaking space. If I swap the non-breaking space with a breaking space, I don't see the issue anymore, but that's more or less probably because the rendered string changes. This issue may not have anything to do with spans, but it seems like too big of a bug to pass with just any old text.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
This bug seems strongly linked to the use of the Bold span. Taking it off of the numbers fixes the problem. That's what I've currently resorted to as a work-around. It'd be nice if there was a better option.

Comment: are you looking for specifics on how to make your text line up properly?  I wasn't sure if you had a question or just reporting some malady

Comment: I was just trying to make it work without having to sacrifice on styles (i.e. removing the bold span to make it work).

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood your problem, just use another SpannableStrinBuilder sb and set text in sb as defined below. i am removing tabs and new lines.

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for(int loop=0 ; loop<(str.length() -1); loop++)
{
  if(!(str.subSequence(loop, loop+1).equals("\t") || 
       str.subSequence(loop, loop+1).equals("\n"))
    )
  {
  sb.append(str.charAt(loop));
  }
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand my problem. There are no tabs or new lines, however they are being shown with them. Look at the picture I posted a bit more carefully.

Comment: have you tried replace function after setting text in text view ?